# @Input emits the first render but doesent emit again again

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am taking the current URL with the router using the below code

```
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
            if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
                this.currentRoute = event.url;
            }
        });
```

then im passing the currentRoute  to a child component via @Input

```
<app-actions *ngIf="currentRoute" [currentRoute]="currentRoute"></app-actions>
```

in my child Component im taking the     `@Input() currentRoute: string;`

issue is that the first time the component is rendered the `currentRoute` is visible but on any next URL change the Router Observable does not provide me with the latest value in the child component.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use ngOnChanges to detect second input. Because child components render only 1 time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Input` does change, you're just not listening to it in the `app-actions`. In your child component, use the `ngOnChanges` life cycle hook like this

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
  console.log(changes);
}
```

Perform a re-assign operation within your `app-actions` component i.e., `this.currentRoute = changes.currentRoute.currentValue` and you're good